# Getting Height of a table on reportlab canvas

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am drawing a table on reportlab canvas. While drawing, we need to pass bottom left coords of the table to the drawOn method. The height of my table is dynamic and therefore it overlaps on the elements above the table. I couldnot find any method that returns the height of a table that is to be drawn. Is there an alternate way to do that?

Comment: What is it more generally that you are trying to do? The Table Flowable handles its positioning on its own and this should not be something you need to do generally.

Comment: Please provide a simple working code to get us started :)

Answer (score 20):

This is such a simple thing that is passively demonstrated but not explicitly addressed in the reportlab documentation:

```
t = Table(tableData, style=tStyle)
t.canv = myCanvas
w, h = t.wrap(0, 0)
```

The variables w and h will then store the table's width and height, respectively.

Comment: This is really important to avoid tables growing upwards into their headings!

   width, height = t.wrap(0,0)
   # Work out where on the document to put the table so it doesn't overlap with the titles.
   bottom_of_table = (18 * cm) - height
   t.drawOn(doc_canvas, self._GetPageCentreX()-(column_width*1.5), bottom_of_table)